# Why won't my jQuery references work? Am I referencing the script incorrectly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reference

I'm trying to write a click event for an arbitrary button on an html page.  I'm referencing jQuery and the JavaScript file in the  here:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/product-swap.js"></script>
```

and the button here:

```
<button class="btn">Click Me</button>
```

I'm really just trying to have an alert appear on the screen to test the references. JavaScript:

```
$('.btn').click(function() {
  console.log("STUPID LOG");
  alert("Won't you appear, please!?");
});
```

When I click the button...nothing happens.  Nothing appears in the log or in the console or in an alert window.

I know this is probably something arbitrary and stupid but I'm fairly new to JavaScript/jQuery and I'm racking my brain over this one.

Thanks!

Comment: It all also depends on the order in which these things appear in your html output. For example if your click handler is attached before the button appearing in the dom it would not work.

Comment: If you're not already doing so, jsfiddle.net is a free and good place to test stuff like this.

Comment: @raider33 much appreciated!  I just won a CodePen Pro subscription, and got it working there, but for some reason didn't need the $(function() { code to do so in that IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this man:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn').on('click', function() {
      console.log("STUPID LOG");
      // Reset the window object
      delete window.alert; 

      alert('test');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the button after the script? If so then you can either move the button to before the script, or wrap the script in a

```
$(function(){ /* Code goes here */ });
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your JQuery lines inside this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //your code.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTML page isn't ready when you call the script, enclose your code with `$(function(){...});`, it will wait until the page is ready.

```
$(function(){
  $('.btn').click(function() {
    console.log("STUPID LOG");
    alert("Fantastic, I will appear!");
  });
});
```

I also recommend you to put your `script` tags at the end of your HTML page, the render of visual elements will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

u can try like this too

```js
function myFunction() {
    alert("I am an alert box!");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</button>
```